# Combining audio and image filters in matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, convolution, fourier

I am trying to write audio and image filtering together code in my project.

Purpose: The main aim of this project is to combine audio with image filters; like for example passing low frequencies of an audio signal while decreasing the brightness of an image, and passing high frequencies while increasing the image brightness.
You can use MATLAB or Simulink or combination of both (through passing a MATLAB code into Simulink)
You can use any of the techniques like convolution, Fourier series, FT, FFT in your project.

```
%This is the code that i just wrote so far
[audio,Fs]=audioread('music.wav');
Ts=1/Fs;
sound(real(audio))
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(audio),grid; %Plotting the sound in time domain


AUDIO=fft(audio);%apply fourier transform to move to the frequency domain
f=-Fs/2:Fs/length(audio):Fs/2-Fs/length(audio);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(f,fftshift(abs(AUDIO))),grid;
```

Comment: You are implying that you have a combined audio stream an and image -- or perhaps a combined video and audio stream (which makes more sense).  Is that the case?  Why not just split it into its constituent video and audio parts, filter them, then combine the result?

Comment: This is the question: "The main aim of this project is to combine audio with image filters; like for example passing low frequencies of an audio signal while decreasing the brightness of an image, and passing high frequencies while increasing the image brightness."

Comment: Is this a _school_ assignment?  If so, please detail that in your question.  It's not clear how the stated task intersects with a reality that includes useful things, so at this point I'm wondering what your prof (or boss) intended here.

Comment: so basically, yes this is a project/research. the question is the one i wrote in the previous comment. we usually know how to do audio filtering and we know how to do image filtering on matlab. The trick here is to combine these 2 filters together (i.e. let them work together). I believe that this could be done using convolution (conv function), but i am not sure how!

Comment: This is Stackexchange.  Stackexchange is different from other forums.  Stackexchange does not like pertinent parts of a question -- or answer -- to be buried in the comments.  **Please edit your question** so that it is complete.

Comment: As to your problem at hand, I believe it is a work psychology issue, not a technical issue.  You need to go talk to your prof and find out what they _really_ want.  It sounds like an XY problem, but the source isn't you.  Try to get your prof to give examples of the end-point behavior they want to see, as if the system were a black box.

Comment: Okay, I just fixed the question, and i included part of my code in case this will help :)